# Qt C++ - QDataStream not reading boolean values

Tags: c++, qt, stream

Hello world, I am working on a project where i can serialize a n object in a file and read it later but when i write the values(boolean value), it works but when i try to read them, this is what i get:

> binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of
>   type bool(or there is no acceptable conversion)

This is my code

```
      void MainWindow::writeSettings()
      {
         QFile *settingsFile = new QFile(":/images/settings_file.txt");

         if(!settingsFile->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
         {
          qDebug() << "File not responsing";

         } else
         {
           QDataStream out(settingsFile);
          out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_3);
          out << settings->getEnableWordWrap();
          out << settings->getShowStatusbar();
          out << settings->getShowToolbar();
}

settingsFile->flush();
settingsFile->close();
```

}

Now if i try to read, get the error

```
         QFile selc(":/images/settings_file.txt");

if(!selc.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    qDebug() << "File not responding";
} else
{
    QDataStream in(&selc);
    in >> settings->getEnableWordWrap() >> settings->getShowStatusbar() >> settings->getShowToolbar();
}

selc.close();
```

`getEnableWordWrap()`, `getShowStatusbar()` and `getShowToolbar()` are all boolean return types.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to change a **value**, the one provide by your getter.

You should prefer extracting your bool values from your stream, before passing them to the right setter:

```
QDataStream in(&selc);
bool tmp;
in >> tmp;
settings->setEnableWordWrap(tmp);
in >> tmp;
settings->setShowStatusbar(tmp);
in >> tmp;
settings->setShowToolbar(tmp);
```

A more oriented object way to achieve that with Qt is to define these two methods to handle QDataStream serialization:

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &, const MySettings &);
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &, MySettings &);
```

Hence, you can deserialize your settings like this:

```
QDataStream in(&selc);
in >> settings;
```

Comment: One could also extract to a universal accessor function. Given a `bool & Settings::enableWordWrap()`, you could simply do `in >> settings->enableWordWrap()`. Sometimes the artificially split getter-setter is a bit of a nuisance.

Comment: @KubaOber: agree on the artificial feeling of getter/setter. But when working with Qt, particularly with QML integration and QObject properties, getter/setter allow to use the notifier signal in the right place.

Comment: The getter/setter and the notifier signal are separate concepts. You can have a getter that returns a reference, usable as a setter, and an explicit setter that accepts the new value as a parameter. Both can coexist, whether you use a notifier signal or not.

Comment: Sure, maybe I am a bit too automatic to take the getter/setter way. It's something that is used a lot in examples and project I look into. Your way have advantages in certain cases.